# I created a 3d walking script and my character goes flying when he walks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { jumpKeyPressed = true; }
    xAxisInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    zAxisInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidBodyComponent.AddForce(new Vector3(xAxisInput, rigidBodyComponent.velocity.y, zAxisInput), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

This is the code that allows him to walk.

Comment: Put 0 at ```rigidBodyComponent.velocity.y``` place. Does it still rocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause you use FroceMode.VelocityChange, when updating force to your object, mass of object is ignored. Thus, your object's velocity will be rigidBodyComponent.velocity.y. Then as a results, your object's velocity.y will be current velocity.y. So, If there is velocity change, you cannot stop your object unless velocity.y is changed. So change ForceMode or makes some constant force toward ground.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.VelocityChange.html